# owl-carousel 2 - не выводит элементы управления

Tags: html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

Ребят! Кто юзает сей дивный плагин. Почему не отображает кнопы влево/вправо? И не срабатывает автоплей. Всё делаю по инструкции с родного сайта. С первой версией не было таких проблем. Не рекомендуйте альтернативы, это уже дело принципа понять проблему.

```
<div id="banner-latest" class="row owl-carousel">
    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
      <div class="product-layout latest col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 item">
          ...
     </div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>

$('#banner-latest').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        items:5,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplayTimeout:5000,
        autoplayHoverPause:true,
        margin:5,
        nav: true,
        navText:["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left fa-5x'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right fa-5x'></i>"]
    });
```

Comment: да этот плагин хороший, но для помощи хоть покажите ваш код! HTML + JS

Comment: Вот. Прокрутка мышей работает, классы подтягиваются. Но никак.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для отображения элементов управления прокруткой в owl-carousel 2, необходимо подключить дополнительный файл из архива, загруженого с офф.сайта - **owl.navigation.js**. Спасибо всем, кто пытался помочь.